# How to filter "visible" jQuery elements hidden by another elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

Well I have this issue , I want to filter a selection of elements (for example the controls of a form) using

```
$controls = $(document).find('.control');
$controls.filter('[required]:visible');
```

This is supposed that will return the controls of the form are visible and required.

The problem is when I have a group of elements hidden, but the elements are visible, for example:

```
<div class="group" style="display:none">
    <div class="control" id="control1" required>
         <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="control" id="control2" required>
         <input type="text" />
    </div>
...
    <div class="control" id="control3">
         <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I filter the controls, I don't get anything because the "group" is hiding  all.

How can I solve it? (I know how, but the question is about the simplicity of `'[required]:visible'`, I want an answer like that, with a selector).

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a problem, it's normal that when the parent is hidden, the children are hidden too. If you want to select all controls (inclusiv hidden), you should just change your selector to ('[required=required]')

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet for your operation:

```js
$controls = $(document).find('.control');
console.log($controls.filter(function(){
 return $(this).css('display') == 'block' && $(this).attr('required') == 'required';
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group" style="display:none">
    <div class="control" id="control1" required>
         <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="control" id="control2" required>
         <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="control" id="control3">
         <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hide the elements, instead of hiding the group?, Or if you are interested in the value of the hidden elements, just remove the `:visible` filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you could share a working fiddle or even a snippet i could have helped you better. But ill still try my best to answer your question.

Firstly, since your parent is hidden your child will be hidden as well(Normal Behaviour)

Secondly, Just try doing this

```
var elem = $(element),
controlElem = elem.find(".control"),
if(controlElem.hasClass("required")){
success code goes here.
```

Also dont forget to change your selector to ('[required=required]')

Hope this helps.